# IndexOutOfBoundException invalid index 20 size is 20

Tags: android, database, listview

Im getting this error when i reach the last row.. IndexOutOfBoundException invalid index 20 size is 20.

This is my code.

```
public class SocialListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private List<Item> items2;
private List<Item> items3;
private List<FacebookItem> fb;
private List<Instagram> insta;

// private MainTable objBean;
private Item objBean;
private Item objBean2;
private Item objBean3;
// private MainTable objBean;

private int row;
private int i;
int layout1 = 0;
int layout2 = 1;
Session session;
String fbpostid;
private InstagramApp mApp;
private InstagramSession mSession;
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
String accessToken;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
String name;
int fbcount;
int instacount;

public SocialListAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList,
        List<Item> arrayList2, List<Item> arrayList3, String name,
        int fbcount, int instacount) {
    // super(act, resource, arrayList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = act;
    this.items = arrayList;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items2 = arrayList2;
    this.items3 = arrayList3;   
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    objBean = items.get(position);
    if (objBean.getI() == 0) {
        return layout1;
    } else if (objBean.getI() == 1) {
        return layout2;
    }
    return i;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    objBean = items.get(position);
     objBean2 = items2.get(position); 
     objBean3 = items3.get(position);

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    i = objBean.getI();
    // if(i == 0){

    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        if (type == layout1) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        } else if (type == layout2) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }



    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;
    if ((items2 == null) || ((position + 1) > items2.size()))
        return view;
    if ((items3 == null) || ((position + 1) > items3.size()))
        return view;


    holder.tvinstatime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instatime);

    holder.tvinstapostid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instapostid);



    if (holder.tvinstapostid != null && null != objBean3.getinstapost_id()
            && objBean3.getinstapost_id().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvinstapostid.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean3
                .getinstapost_id()));
    }


    if (holder.tvinstatime != null && null != objBean3.getdatetime()
            && objBean3.getdatetime().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvinstatime.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean3.getdatetime()));
    }


    holder.ivimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fbdp);
    holder.buttonlike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.likelist);

    if (holder.tvfbpostid != null && null != objBean.getfbpost_id()
            && objBean.getfbpost_id().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvfbpostid.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getfbpost_id()));
    }

    return view;
}
```

here i am using three array list .

the first one is to get the flag and on that it depends on which layout to chose,

Second one is to get the details of fb

Third one is to get the datails of instagram.

i am getting error on this line

```
 objBean2 = items2.get(position);
```

when i scroll to the last.

Comment: items2 size and items1 size should be same...

Comment: item2 + item3 = item1

Comment: Note that ListView reuses visible items so indexes will not be always what you expect...

Comment: so what should i do now??

Comment: In get count return `items2.size()`

Comment: i can return only one variable in get count return

Comment: Make a try/catch so program will continue. Did that too sometimes, works perfectly.

Comment: Yes!! Thank You very much worked perfectly... Post this as an answer i will accept it...

Comment: I wouldn't suggest just catching all your errors.. Not only could this prevent some code from executing, it also encourages bad design. You should fix the underlying issue.

Comment: Give me a better solution...

Comment: I agree with @Snailer!